# Android (full screen website in chrome): Soft keyboard not closing properly showing white space

Tags: android, keyboard, fullscreen, mobile-website

I made a full screen html/php website with an input zone.

Below is the minimal content of the html/php file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
input{padding:0.4em; font-size:0.6em;}
</style>
</head>
<body style="background-image: url('bkg.jpg'); margin:100px; font-size:3em;">
<?php
print_r($_GET); 
?>
<form method='get'>
<input type='text' name='test'>
<input type='submit' value='Send !'>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Content of the Json file:

```
{
  "short_name": "test",
  "name": "test",
  "start_url": "test.php",
  "display": "fullscreen",
  "orientation": "landscape"
}
```

When clicking “submit” either on the soft keyboard or the input button, the keyboard doesn’t close properly and lets a white space over the screen although the page is reloading (see picture, n°3).

I have to touch the screen or reload the web page to mask the white space (picture n°4).

Thanks for help.

[Link to the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLgIf.jpg)